# "BOOST_DIR NOT FOUND" of shark3.0 using boost1.54.0 with cmake under win7 x64 os

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, cmake, shark-ml

[shark3.0](http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/index.html) is a machine learning library which is dependent on the boost library. I want to cmake shark3.0 with cmake-gui into msvc9.0 sln and to generate `shark.lib`.

In cmake-gui, i configure everything other than "BOOST_DIR" with the right path of boost components. As mentioned in the title, i can not solve it, even with the tip of shark "get-started" help! In the webpage of "get-started", it mentions that I don't have to worry about `"BOOST_DIR NOT FOUND"`, and can CMAKE (that is, "generate" )it successfully. But,unfortunately, I can not!!!!

By the way, the boost1.54.0 in my situation is from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.54.0/), it is generated by `"boost_1_54_0_msvc_9.0_win32.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

the key point is in the following sentence: "CMake Error at G:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:644 (file):
  file STRINGS file "D:/library_file/boost_1_54_0/**boost/boost/**version.hpp" ", when i use cmake-gui to configure and generate the sln version of shark!

"D:/library_file/boost_1_54_0/boost/" is the folder where all .hpp header files are included especially "version.hpp". so, if i want to generate sln of shark, i have to put a new file folder "boost" in "D:/library_file/boost_1_54_0/boost/" and copy "version.hpp" into the new "boost" folder. done well!